# I have a Lenovo Legion 5, with NVIDIA GeForce RTX and AMD Radeon graphics, AMD Ryzen 7000 Series 7

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, radeon

At first, I encountered difficulty in connecting a secondary screen through HDMI. Following advice from a forum, I proceeded to install the Nvidia 535 drivers and diligently followed all necessary instructions. Consequently the additional screen was successfully detected, however upon attempting to alter the display layout from anything other than a mirrored setup to an extended screen or a vertical monitor, the entire display began to exhibit shaking behavior, rendering the computer unresponsive. The only recourse in such instances was to press the power button and initiate a restart. During this restart process, I observed error messages indicating the resolution of prior issues, after which the system loaded correctly. Should I endeavor to reconnect the screen, the issue resurfaces?

I have undertaken the installation of different versions of Ubuntu, having performed five distinct installations. I possess a prevailing suspicion that my challenges stem from an inability to locate precise driver instructions tailored to my particular system configuration.

In summary, the secondary screen within Ubuntu 22.04.2 is indeed recognized, but upon connection it exhibits erratic behavior.

[image: Screen view]

System:

Lenovo Legion 5 Pro, with NVIDIA GeForce RTX and AMD Radeon graphics, AMD Ryzen 7000 Series 7.

```
H/W path          Device        Class       Description
=======================================================
                                system      Computer
/0                              bus         Motherboard
/0/0                            memory      31GiB System memory
/0/1                            processor   AMD Ryzen 7 7745HX with Radeon Graph
/0/100                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/0.2                      generic     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.1                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.1/0                    display     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1.1/0.1    card0         multimedia  NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1.1/0.1/0  input15       input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1.1/0.1/1  input16       input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1.1/0.1/2  input17       input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1.1/0.1/3  input18       input       HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/1.2                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0      /dev/nvme0    storage     SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2
/0/100/1.2/0/0    hwmon2        disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/2    /dev/ng0n1    disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/1.2/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1  disk        NVMe disk
/0/100/2.1                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/2.2                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/2.2/0      wlp4s0        network     Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
/0/100/3.1                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/3.2                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/3.3                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/3.3/0      enp7s0        network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabi
/0/100/8.1                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0      /dev/fb0      display     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/AT
/0/100/8.1/0.2                  generic     VanGogh PSP/CCP
/0/100/8.1/0.3                  bus         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.4                  bus         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.5                  multimedia  Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio
/0/100/8.1/0.6    card1         multimedia  Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio
/0/100/8.1/0.6/0  input19       input       HD-Audio Generic Mic
/0/100/8.1/0.6/1  input20       input       HD-Audio Generic Headphone
/0/100/8.3                      bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.3/0                    bus         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/14                       bus         FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                     bridge      FCH LPC Bridge
/0/100/14.3/0                   system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/14.3/1                   system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/14.3/2                   system      PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/14.3/3                   system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/14.3/4                   system      PnP device PNP0c01
/0/100/14.3/5                   generic     PnP device KBC8042
/0/100/14.3/6     input8        input       Ideapad extra buttons
/0/101                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/102                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/103                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/104                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/105                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/106                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/107                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/108                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/109                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/10a                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/10b                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/10c                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/10d                          bridge      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/1                input0        input       Power Button
/2                input1        input       Lid Switch
/3                input11       input       ELAN06FA:00 04F3:327E Touchpad
/4                input12       input       PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
/5                input13       input       ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyb
/6                input14       input       ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wire
/7                input2        input       Power Button
/8                input21       input       Integrated Camera: Integrated C
/9                input3        input       AT Raw Set 2 keyboard
/a                input4        input       Video Bus
/b                input9        input       ELAN06FA:00 04F3:327E Mouse
```